# Eliminate repeated code Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have multiple navigation controllers and their root view controllers in my app. I want each navigation bar to have social media buttons closely placed on the right side of the bar. For the same I have used this code to show the buttons in 1 view controller:

```
    let fbImage = UIImage(named: "Facebook.png")!
    let twitterImage = UIImage(named: "Twitter.png")!
    let youtbImage = UIImage(named:"YouTube.png")!

    let fbBtn: UIButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    fbBtn.setImage(fbImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
    fbBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.fbBtnPressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    fbBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    let fbBarBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: fbBtn)

    let twitterBtn: UIButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    twitterBtn.setImage(twitterImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
    twitterBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.twitterBtnPressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    twitterBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    let twitterBarBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: twitterBtn)

    let youtbBtn: UIButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    youtbBtn.setImage(youtbImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
    youtbBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.youtubeBtnPressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    youtbBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    let youtbBarBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: youtbBtn)

    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([youtbBarBtn, twitterBarBtn, fbBarBtn], animated: false)
```

Now I want the same buttons on all navigations bars. I can easily copy this code and respective target methods in `viewDidLoad()` of each view controller, but too much code is getting repeated. So how can avoid this situation?

I am using Swift 3. I am new to iOS. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You could set a common "parent" from your UIViewController, like "CommonViewController", put that code in it, and each of your ViewController would inherit from CommonViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most duplications are solved by using functions. The first step is to extract that code into a function, the second step is to use the same function from multiple places.

You can add it to an extension, for example:

```
extension UIViewController {
     func addShareButtons() {
         ...
         self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([youtbBarBtn, twitterBarBtn, fbBarBtn], animated: false)
     }
}
```

and only call

```
self.addShareButtons()
```

from every controller that needs the buttons.

You can add button handlers to the extension too.

Another method is to use a `UIViewController` subclass but that's always a problem if you want to use a `UITableViewController` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You can design a custom navigation controller and add these code to the navigation controller. inherit the navigation controller to your storyboard or programmatically where you want to use.

//sample code

```
class "YourNavigationCorollerName": UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate { 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        //declare here you code, what you want
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these buttons ALWAYS have the same behavior, you can create a custom class for them, and place the repeated code there. For instance:

```
class FacebookButton : UIButton {

    override init() {

        super.init()
        self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        self.setImage(UIImage(named: "Facebook.png")!, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

...I think the compiler will yell at you for initializing a UIView without a decoder and frame, but hopefully you get the idea.

To improve on this, you could 1) create a custom UINavigationController with the UIBarButtonItems you want to use, and reuse that controller, and/or 2) create a protocol like the following:

```
protocol FacebookBtnHandler {
    func fbBtnPressed()
}
```

...and have any relevant VCs conform to it. This would allow you to assign the target and selector for the button in the FacebookButton init method, where you assign the image and frame, and hence prevent repetition of that line, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement bar button by creating subclass of `UIBarButton`

```
class Button: UIBarButtonItem {
    convenience init(withImage image : UIImage,Target target: Any, andSelector selector: Any?){

        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        button.addTarget(target, action: selector, for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        self.init(customView: button)
    }
}


let fbImage = UIImage(named: "Facebook.png")!
let twitterImage = UIImage(named: "Twitter.png")!
let youtbImage = UIImage(named:"YouTube.png")!

let fbBtn = Button(withImage: fbImage, Target: self, andSelector: #selector(HomeViewController.fbBtnPressed))

let twitterBtn = Button(withImage: fbImage, Target: self, andSelector: #selector(HomeViewController.twitterBtnPressed))

let youtubeBtn = Button(withImage: fbImage, Target: self, andSelector: #selector(HomeViewController.youtubeBtnPressed))

self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([youtbBarBtn, twitterBarBtn, fbBarBtn], animated: false)
```

and make it for all your view controller

```
extension UIViewController {
     func addButtons() {
         // add above code 
     }
}
```